# Entity Framework performance difference with many includes

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

In my application I have a big nasty query that uses 25 includes. I know that might be a bit exessive, but it haven't given us much problems and have been working fine. If I take the query generated by EF and run it manually in the database it takes around 500ms, and from the code EF uses around 700ms to get the data from the database and build up the object structure, and that is perfectly acceptable.

The problem however is on the production server. If I run the query manually there I see the same around 500ms time usage to fetch the data, but entity framework now uses around 11000ms to get the data and build the object, and that is of course not good by any measure.

So my question is: What can be the cause of these extreme differences when the query fired manually on the database is roughly the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Entity Framework in a more "manual" way.

So instead of using `dbContext.Set<T>` and a lot of includes, I had to manually use a series of `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>("select something from something else")`. After a bit of painful coding binding all the objects together I tested it on the machines that had the problem, and now it worked as expected on all machines.

So I don't know why it worked on some machines and not others, but it seems that EF has problems on some machine setups when there are a great deal of includes.